# Area of a multivariate Gaussian beyond a hyperplane

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution

Given a multivariate Gaussian over the domain, $\Bbb{R}^n$ with mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix, $\Sigma$. For simplicity sake, we can consider the case where $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix. I'd like to find the probability that this distribution lies in the region: $\sum c_i x_i \leq b$. We can assume the $c_i$'s and $b$ are all positive if it matters. In other words, the area under the curve for that region.

The original problem was for a multivariate Binomial consisting of $n$ independent binomials. The problem was that there were a lot of points in the region of interest and the probability had to be calculated repeatedly.

So, I figured approximating them with a multivariate Gaussian would make it simpler but if this can be done for a multivariate Binomial, even better.

---

One way to do this would be with simulation. Importance sampling will give us a pretty good estimate with a few samples. I'm wondering if there is something more exact. Perhaps with numerical integration?

Comment: What you're asking is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^k\text{det}(\mathbf \Sigma)}}\prod_{i=1}^n\int_{\sum_i c_ix_i\leq b}dx_i\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n\Sigma^{-1}_{jj}(x_j-\mu_j)\right)?$$

Comment: Yes, although the prod sign should be inside the integral, right?

Comment: Alright. This prod notation I used means $n$ integrations with respect to each $x_i$, but yes, it could go inside. Also, I just noticed $(x_j-\mu_j)$ should be squared.

Comment: For a Gaussian $X$, $Z = \langle c,X\rangle $ is 1-D Gaussian with mean $\nu = \langle c,\mu\rangle$ and variance $\sigma^2 = c^\top \Sigma c.$ So you want to compute $P(Z \le b) = P( (Z-\nu)/\sigma \le (b-\nu)/\sigma)$. But $(Z-\nu)/\sigma$ is a standard Gaussian random variable, and its tails are a standard library function (often the so-called [error-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) is implemented), which you can directly use. Or for that matter if you want to numerically integrate, then it's usually much better to do that in one-dimension than in many.